# how to save state in spring mvc 3.1?

Tags: java

I don't know if it is "save state" the word, but if i have this method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
        model.addAttribute("email", new Email());
        model.addAttribute("imgBg", getRandomBg(request.getRemoteHost()));
        Map sexoOpts = new HashMap();
        sexoOpts.put("M", "homem");
        sexoOpts.put("F", "mulher");

        Map sexoOpts2 = new HashMap();
        sexoOpts2.put("M", "Busco por homens");
        sexoOpts2.put("F", "Busco por mulheres");

        model.addAttribute("sexoList1", sexoOpts);
        model.addAttribute("sexoList2", sexoOpts2);
        return "index";
    }
```

and in other method i have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save-email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doSaveEmail(@Valid @ModelAttribute("email") Email email,BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
        model.addAttribute("imgBg", getRandomBg(request.getLocalAddr()));
        Map sexoOpts = new HashMap();
        sexoOpts.put("M", "homem");
        sexoOpts.put("F", "mulher");

        Map sexoOpts2 = new HashMap();
        sexoOpts2.put("M", "Busco por homens");
        sexoOpts2.put("F", "Busco por mulheres");

        model.addAttribute("sexoList1", sexoOpts);
        model.addAttribute("sexoList2", sexoOpts2);

        if (result.hasErrors()){
            return "index";
        }
        Date date = new Date();
        email.setCreationDate(date);

        boolean saved = false;
        try{
            saved = emailBo.saveEmail(email);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        model.addAttribute("email", new Email());
        if (saved){
            model.addAttribute("saveStatus", "ok");
        }else{
            model.addAttribute("saveStatus", "false");
        }


        return "index";
    }
```

I have to recreate the hashmap to put the sexy options every time since it will go back again to the same page (index.jsp)? there is not a way to save this when i go from home to save-email and back?

Comment: i can re-use the Model that comes in home method in doSaveEmail method? if yes i'll not need to re-add it to the model in doSaveEmail method...

Answer (score 0):

I would save the `Map` as a constant, that way it lives outside of the method, but can still be referenced from within.

```
public class MyController {
    private static Map sexoOpts = new HashMap();
    private static Map sexoOpts2 = new HashMap();

    static {
        sexoOpts.put("M", "homem");
        sexoOpts.put("F", "mulher");
        sexoOpts2.put("M", "Busco por homens");
        sexoOpts2.put("F", "Busco por mulheres");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        //I have access to sexoOpts and sexoOpts2, so there is no
        //need to instantiate them in here anymore...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save-email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doSaveEmail(@Valid @ModelAttribute("email") Email email,BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
        //I have access to sexoOpts and sexoOpts2, so there is no
        //need to instantiate them in here anymore...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "spring way" would be to declare the two hashmaps as instance variables and wire them in your application context (DI) - maybe store the mapping in a properties-file.